# Координаты из XML

Tags: javascript

```
downloadUrl('Marker1.xml', function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var PolygonArrays = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('PolygonArrays');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(PolygonArrays, function(PolygonArraysElem) {
var name = PolygonArraysElem.getAttribute('name');
var path1 = PolygonArraysElem.getAttribute('path');
var triangleCoords = [{lat:  46.702823, lng: 32.577943},{lat:  46.654846, lng:  32.606846},{lat: 46.680626, lng:  32.624165}];
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
      map: map,

      paths: triangleCoords,

      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    });
    });
```

Почему при использовании такого кода

`paths: triangleCoords` верный, 
а если сделать `paths:path1` - неверный,

выборку делает верно, `alert( path1 )` показывает эти же параметры, но на карте не отбражается, могу предположить чтото с типом получаемых данных.

PS с маркерами разобрался, теперь с многоугольниками загвоздка...

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо за правильное напраление))) долго не мог обойти ошибку парсера, все оказалось просто  xml файл надо записывать вместо строки        path1=[{lat:  46.702823, lng: 32.577943},{lat:  46.654846, lng:  32.606846},{lat: 46.680626, lng:  32.624165}]" строку

```
<b>path1="[{&quot;lat&quot;:  46.702823, &quot;lng&quot;: 32.577943},{&quot;lat&quot;:  46.654846, &quot;lng&quot;:  32.606846},{&quot;lat&quot;: 46.680626, &quot;lng&quot;:  32.624165}]"
```

парсер не принимает без двойных кавычек ""параметры lat, а хml не отдает эти кавычки, пришлось вместо " использовать

```
&quot;
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `triangleCoords` - массив точек, а `path1` - строка.

```
var path1 = JSON.parse(PolygonArraysElem.getAttribute('path'));
console.log(path1);
```